# Google Sheets API (Python Client) is inserting data uncontrollably with update and append methods after execution

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm facing an issue with the google sheets API using Python and I can't seem to find any other similar question online about it. I will insert data using the update and append methods, the execution is completed successfully with no errors. Then I'll change the range parameter to update a different column, and BEFORE I run the code with a new range argument, and the service account starts randomly inserting multiple different arrays of data into the spreadsheet without me doing anything. It's not the same exact values I originally inserted, but they are the same dimension and have the same column values.

I'm playing around with a small 5x4 pandas dataframe to get a feel for how to interact with the api. To make things even more strange, the values of the toy dataframe are randomly generated, so I know it's not just running the same update/append over and over again. New dataframe values are being generated each time and I have no idea how that's possible. This is the code I'm executing:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# build a resource from json credentials
service_acct_credentials = 'path_to_credentials.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(filename=service_acct_credentials)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# create a 5x3 dataframe with random int values
df_rand = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(5, 3)), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

# generate a list of 5 dates between today and 1 year ago today
one_year_ago = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=365)
dates = [one_year_ago + datetime.timedelta(days = np.random.randint(1, 365)) for _ in range (5)]

# turn list of dates into a 5x1 dataframe
df_date = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['D'], dtype=str)

# join both ifs into a 5x4 dataframe
df = df_rand.join(df_date, how='left').reset_index(drop=True)

# convert dataframe to a list of dataframe rows, casted to strings, including the column names
values = df.T.reset_index().T.to_numpy(dtype=str).tolist()

service.spreadsheets().values().update(                        
                        spreadsheetId='1obMvYaote-agFUuDv1bQVYcRr9KqkrdecPh3ErTykWQ',
                        valueInputOption='RAW',
                        range='{}!{}'.format('sheet2', 'A2'),
                        body=dict(major_dimension='ROWS', values=values)
                        ).execute()
```

I run the last block of code which successfully updates A2:D7.

In the same block of code, I change the range value to G10, which I would expect to insert the **exact** same values in G10:H15.

```py
service.spreadsheets().values().update(                        
                        spreadsheetId='1obMvYaote-agFUuDv1bQVYcRr9KqkrdecPh3ErTykWQ',
                        valueInputOption='RAW',
                        range='{}!{}'.format('sheet2', 'G10'),
                        body=dict(major_dimension='ROWS', values=values)
                        ).execute()
```

I don't run the code block, (which again is the same code block that had range **A2**, just replaced with **G10** - not copied and pasted or anything, which shouldn't make a difference in execution anyways). But replacing the string value in the range argument of the request body seemed to trigger the resource or service to start inserting random values uncontrollably (in columns A-D).

Here is a screenshot of the first ~40 or so rows of data that's being added by the service account. Everything up to row 7 was what I intended to be inserted by a single request, but after row 8 is what's happening uncontrollably. You can see that the values are different every time a new "A, B, C, D" row starts, and this cycle repeats all the way to **ROW 2148**

[image: google_sheet_screenshot]

I've tried the following:

- Assigning update method object to the variable **request**, before assessing the execute method.

```py
request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(                        
                        spreadsheetId='1obMvYaote-agFUuDv1bQVYcRr9KqkrdecPh3ErTykWQ',
                        valueInputOption='RAW',
                        range='{}!{}'.format('sheet1', 'A2'),
                        body=dict(major_dimension='ROWS', values=values)
                        )
```

I don't even have to run `request.execute()`, the google sheet starts continuously adding new rows of data on its own.

- Closing the http resource by running `service.close()`, it does not successfully close. I check the google sheet after to see if the updating stopped and it did not.
- Restarting the code editor I'm using. When I do that, after a few minutes the service account stops adding data to the sheet. However, as soon as I start over and execute a single request, it starts back up again.
- Using a different worksheet within the same spreadsheet.
- Using a different spreadsheet altogether.
- Using a different machine and virtual environment entirely.

No results with the last 3 either

To paint a picture of just how excessively this is happening - I checked the API dashboard on the cloud console, and for Google Sheets *alone* it showed a whopping total of 3,853 api calls submitted in the past **24 hours**. ~100 of those api calls were actually my explicit doing. No other user has access to my service credentials or cloud project, etc.

I'm sorry for the long explanation, I'm totally lost and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: When I tested your showing script, the values are put to only the cells "A2:D7". So I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My apologizes, I didn't want to be overkill with such a lengthy question already. I'm pretty new to stack overflow, what would you suggest to be the best way to share more of my code (colab notebook, GitHub, etc)?

Comment: I added more info to my question, I hope that makes more sense

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No need to apologize! Your English is great. I understand why you don't understand my question, it was hard for me to explain it myself so I can see how it's confusing. Maybe I can try replicating the problem again and screen recording it and linking the recording to see the exact issue. Thank you for your reply & willingness to help.